# Schedule funtion to Pull CSV file to database

Tags: csv, asp.net-web-api, scheduler

Sorry, I have not done any coding in WEB API so I don't have any sample to share here.
But I just wanted to know that, how we can schedule a task on server for WEB API to read a csv file after every 15 or 30 mins.

From client we are successfully able to push csv to my ftp server where my application is located. But how to retrieve the data from csv after every fixed interval?

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI is the wrong tool for the job.

You can certainly *push* (or *upload* specifically) CSV data to a WebAPI method, and that method can do whatever you need to do with that data.  But WebAPI doesn't run on a timer.  It's not going to periodically look for data to process, you have to *send it* that data.

A web application is a request/response system.  In order to do something, you have to send it a request.

For an application that periodically runs on a timer, consider a Windows Service or even simply a Console Application which is scheduled to run with some job scheduler (Windows Task Scheduler, cron, etc.).  That would run periodically without the need for input or a user interface at all.

Now, if the code you need to use is in the WebAPI application already, that's ok.  You can refactor that code into a separate Class Library in the same solution as the WebAPI application.  Then add the new application (Windows Service or Console Application) to that solution and reference that same Class Library.  Both applications can share the same supporting code.  Indeed, the application layer should be as thin as possible over a set of common business logic that can be shared by multiple applications.